# Is there a way to view cPickle or Pickle file contents without loading Python in Windows?

Tags: python, pickle

I use cPickle to save data sets from each run of a program. Since I sometimes need to see the outline of the data without running the code, I would like an easy way to quickly view the contents by just double-clicking on the file. I am trying to avoid having to load a terminal and pointing python to a file each time, just to run some `print` script.

I looked for Notepad++ plugins but couldn't find anything.

Is there some easy way to do this? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Note: I run Windows 7.

Comment: You can `pickle` using an [ASCII protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format), which would be readable from notepad(even though it wont look nice, especially if you put there complex objects).

Comment: I've just created a way to unpickle things using dynamically created (fake) modules and classes - it should help people  reaching here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54048296/108205

Answer (score 74, accepted):

For Python 3.2+/2.7+ you can view (`__repr__`'s of) pickles from the command-line:

```
$ python -c "import pickle; pickle.dump({'hello': 'world'}, open('obj.dat', 'wb'))"
$ python -mpickle obj.dat
{'hello': 'world'}
```

It should be easy to integrate this into the Windows shell.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for when I googled this question (in 2017). It should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: Very useful! It seems to work with Python 2.7 pickles as well, at least for the single case where I needed this.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner thanks I updated the answer. Probably it was backported.

Comment: I tried this, and the example here worked, but not the pickle I saved. I got: 
```File "/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyshark/packet/fields.py", line 88, in __new__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_default_value'
```

Comment: @JoelCross I am not sure that `__repr__` can give always correct, de-serializable values. It prints essentially a tree structure where any node can by a reference of any other node in the tree. This data structure can't be serialized on an easy way. In this case, the accepted answer focuses the perfectness, while this answer the practical usability and both have the right to exist (note, also I found this answer useful in my specific case).

Comment: This blew my mind. I've been loading them manually for years. So much time to be saved using this method!

Comment: I'd never seen a pickle file before today. Found this because I'd like to view its contents, but when I run `python -mpickle mock.pickle`, I get no output.  It's a 2.1M file and I can see a few words if I do `strings mock.pickle`.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @hepcat72 Try `python -mpickletools mock.pickle` - it might at least get you a start. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks @nealmcb. This was long enough ago that I can't even remember how I'd encountered this issue, so I'll have to keep this in mind if I ever need it again.

Comment: +1 This is a useful answer. @nth how would you force it to output the JSON with double quotes without another pipe? (otherwise, some commands, like `jq` have problems reading it).

Answer (score 14):

I *REALLY* doubt that there's any way to do this since with `pickle`, you can pack in pretty much anything.  When unpickling, you need to be able to load the modules etc. that were loaded when the object was pickled.  In other words, in general, to be able to `unpickle` something, python needs to be able to reproduce the "environment" of the program (or at least a close enough approximation) -- loaded modules, classes in the global namespace, etc ...  In general, this isn't possible without some help from the user.  Consider:

```
import pickle
class Foo(object): pass

a = Foo()
with open('data.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a,f)
```

Now if you try to restore this in a separate script, python has no way of knowing what a `Foo` looks like and so it can't restore the object (unless you define an suitable `Foo` object in that script).  This isn't really a process that can be done without some human intervention.

Of course, an arguably useful special case where you're just pickling builtin objects and things from the standard library might be able to be attempted ... but I don't think you could write a general unpickler extension.

Comment: No idea about pickle, but there's nothing stopping a protocol from storing all the necessary information of the "environment" in its output as well. In this case that would be fairly trivial: We stored one new-style class with no extra parameters. So it certainly is possible to do so - it may just mean storing quite a bit of extra information.

Answer (score 11):

You can also make an alias on your terminal, for example :

```
alias pvw="python -mpickle "
```

in my case :

```
pvw obj.dat                                   
         ID    A_ID   B_ID   PAST_ID
    0    20    1008   4771     425  
    1    20    2000   4771     425  
    2    20    2015   4771     425
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by nth is often all you need:

`python -m pickle data.pickle`

@mgilson makes the point that if the pickle contains user-defined data types, that method will fail, e.g. with

`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Foo' on <module 'pickle' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/pickle.py'>`

In that case, you can still get at least some information via [pickletools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickletools.html), which is also safer since it doesn't execute any pickle bytecode:

```
$ python -m pickletools data.pickle 
    0: \x80 PROTO      4
    2: \x95 FRAME      23
   11: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE '__main__'
   21: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
   22: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'Foo'
   27: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 1)
   28: \x93 STACK_GLOBAL
   29: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 2)
   30: )    EMPTY_TUPLE
   31: \x81 NEWOBJ
   32: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 3)
   33: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 4
```

Adding the `-a` option explains the bytecodes. I dare say that there are some clever schemes out there to make that prettier and more helpful, but it is a start.